# Not able to figure out Multi Class Multi Label Problem in Tensorflow using an array of integers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset of 2000 rows that contains 6 columns. I generated the dataset where for every set of 4 points, acoustic1 and acoustic2 gets calculated. The table is shown below:

|  | Acoustic1 | Acoustic2 | Point1 | Point2 | Point3 | Point4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 76.111834 | 0.925563 | 4 | 8 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 71.802400 | 0.630801 | 4 | 8 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 75.495011 | 0.611434 | 4 | 8 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 77.197198 | 0.726548 | 4 | 8 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 64.907666 | 0.569464 | 4 | 3 | 6 | 9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1995 | 77.846542 | 0.709880 | 1 | 9 | 3 | 3 |
| 1996 | 70.794275 | 0.710815 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 4 |
| 1997 | 72.669395 | 0.766655 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 4 |
| 1998 | 84.141842 | 0.673028 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 4 |
| 1999 | 74.571967 | 0.656891 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 4 |

[Screenshot of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kcuG.png)

Acoustic 1 and Acoustic 2 are float numbers and Locations are integers between 0 to 9. I am trying to train the model to learn which array or 'set' or Points from 1 to 4 corresponds to which Acoustic 1 and 2 values. The end goal is to be able to save the model and predict the Points 1 to 4 in order to achieve desired Acoustic1 and Acoustic2 values.

The problem I am having is that I am not being able to fully figure out how to setup and shape the model. This is what I am currently trying:

```
xp = data[['Point1','Point2','Point3','Point4']].to_numpy()
X = data.iloc[:,0:2]
y = xp
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 21)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(2,), activation='relu')) #I think my input shape may be incorrect and I am not able to figure this out completely
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My loss is off the charts, and the accuracy is extremely poor. Is someone out there able to figure out what the issue may be? Your advice would be much appreciated. If a colab file would be helpful to see let me know and I can provide a link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before doing train_test_split, you should scale your data. [See how Data Scaling Improve Deep Learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-improve-neural-network-stability-and-modeling-performance-with-data-scaling/).  Neural network doesn't work too well when your input is big.  Acoustic 1 definitely should be re-scaled.

If you are expecting your model to be highly non-linear, you should consider using sigmoid activation in the first hidden layer (i.e., the one with 128 units).  relu is mostly linear.

Good luck!